# server and postgresql cannot connect when both running on Docker `getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND`

Tags: postgresql, docker, containers, nestjs, typeorm

after creating docker containers with docker compose file (below), I call

`$ docker run myApp`

However, I get

`Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND main_db`

this only happens when both server and postgresql are in docker containers (I am able to connect to postgresql on localhost)

I'm running a NestJS app using TypeOrm to connect to a postgresql server

inside the `app.module.ts` where it boots up the connection my config should match my docker postgresql config. the `host` points to the container I created on docker `main_db` and I declared this as a dependency of my server, the `main` service. Everything should be on the same network `webnet`.:

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'postgres', 
      host: 'main_db',
      port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: dbLogging,
    }),
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  main:
    container_name: main
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT}:${SERVER_PORT}
      - 9229:9229
    command: npm run start:dev
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - webnet
    depends_on:
      - main_db
  main_db:
    container_name: main_db
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    networks:
      - webnet
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      PG_DATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}'
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  webnet:
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

`.env` file

```
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=test
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test
POSTGRES_DB=test
SERVER_PORT=3001
```

Comment: If you're just using `docker run`, that doesn't consult the `docker-compose.yml` file at all: it won't see the Compose network, other containers, or your instructions to use an old `node_modules` tree instead of what's in the image.  You need to use `docker-compose` commands.

Comment: This is my first project using docker, so I'm probably misunderstanding the infrastructure. I do have a `Dockerfile` as well; however, inside that code I don't see any reference to the `docker-compose.yml` file. I will research the `docker-compose` commands thanks.

Comment: thank you @DavidMaze, I was simply not running the `docker-compose` file. by calling `docker-compose up` I got the application to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file and you call `docker run myApp` for the app defined inside of the `Dockerfile` instead of calling `docker-compose up`, you will see the app running; however, it will not start the containers defined in the `docker-compose` file. In the case of the NestJS server, it was running the server, but could not find the container with the database, since this container was not being spun up. Although the distinction between the app setup in the `Dockerfile` and the definition of the containers in the `docker-compose.yml` was clear, I didn't realize that the `docker` command didn't reference the `docker-compose.yml`. Thus, posting here in case anyone else has a similar confusion.